# ISO - helpdesk solution with many integrations

Tags: help-desk, asset-management

I am in search of the best helpdesk / servicedesk for my company. We create software and hardware solutions for retail and industrial clients.

It should have the following features:

1. Create requests via phone, WhatsApp, web form, and chat.
2. Asset management. Tie assets to tickets, track service contracts, & track hardware warranties.
3. Hosted in the USA by an established company (over 5 years old).
4. Able to integrate with Jira, TeamViewer, Salesforce, Opsgenie, Microsoft IOT, Pagerduty, & Microsoft Teams.

I have administered Zendesk in the past, which would work, and I like it well enough, but I'm casting a wide net to see if there is a particular solution I might be unaware of. I am not a developer so the product needs to be a low-code or no-code solution which does not require a dedicated staff person for administration or hiring a third party. As such, I have already ruled out Microsoft Dynamics 365, Salesforce Service Cloud, and ServiceNow.